# How many volts is needed to power a coil

Tags: transformer, coil, electromagnet

I recently encountered and was trying to troubleshoot a device that's not working properly. In tracing the functionally of the device, I isolated the issue with a coil that does not activate.

Unfortunately, there's no diagram and/or any useful information to follow. I just have a picture of the coil, and at this point, I'm just trying to figure out how many volts would I need to directly power this coil.

I did try to apply 11 (and 13) DC volts, and the coil did **not** budge. I tested and there **is** continuity across the coil leads.

At this point, I'm looking for the correct way to power this coil.

[image: coil]

Comment: A coil is just a hunk of copper, essentially a piece of looped wire. So I hope that makes you think about what "powered up" and "activates" and "budge" (move) mean for a lone coil. A coil does not inherently have activatation or power up requirements nor does it move on its own. In other words, you aren't giving us enough information about the coil and how it is being used.

Comment: @lzc:  Is it a [coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor) or is it a [solenoid?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#Electromechanical_solenoid)

Comment: The markings appear to be Russian or some other similar language.  It might help if you could find someone to translate into English.

Comment: A bit of context as what device the coil is in, and what it's mechanically attached to might help as well. What's the resistance of the coil?

Comment: I know you probably feel like you have provided all relevant information. But there are a lot of things you haven't said. Right now, the only way the question could be resolved is if the Cyrillic writing can be deciphered so that the operating voltage can be determined. Here are some questions. Maybe you can edit your question to add this information. Did this machine used to work, and then it just stopped working one day? Was the coil wired when you started troubleshooting? Can't you trace those wires back where they came from to determine the operating voltage? Or use a volt meter?

Comment: Thanks, @DKNguyen for making me "think" about this a little more.

Comment: Also, @JRE, you made me think, I would have to guess it's a solenoid.

Comment: To @mkeith, this contraption "did work" before (that's what I was told)... When I approached it, there were lots of wires stripped out and no schematic to follow. I'm trying with the help of this wonderful forum to reverse-engineer this monstrosity:)

This "hunk of copper" looks like it's supposed to pull a piston that's connected to a lever, whenever the coil has the appropriate power (which is my OP issue) it should be pulling on this thingy.

I did not measure is the resistance across the coil leads. Could that help me in determining how many volts are needed to power up this coil?

Comment: I am assuming that the in your photo 23+/-2 is the resistance. How big is this thing and how much does it weigh?

Comment: @DKNguyen, it is at most 3" in size

Comment: For that size solenoid, the coil will need about 1A so the Voltage can be determined by the resistance which seems to be 23 ohms so a 24V supply.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I will try to translate this Russian text at least to justify my Slavic name Cyril:) By the way, Russian is very close to my Bulgarian.

*Тисо-Продакшин* is *Tiso-Production* - maybe the producer

*EМ-87* - I don't know what it is... maybe 87 is the year

*Rобм* is *Rcoil* ("обмотка" is "coil"), i.e. this is the coil resistance = 23 Ohm

*W = 1520вит.* means W = 1520 turns ("витка" is "turn of winding")

*ПЭТВ-2. 0,415* describes the copper wire:

Wire Enameled ...  0,415 probably means 0.415 mm diameter of the wire

---

*Tips*:

- Do not hold the coil terminals when switching the voltage on and off. Do you have any idea what "self-induction" is?
- Increase the voltage and apply it for a short time (1 ÷ 2 seconds). Basically, the coil is a voltage integrator so the current increases gradually starting from zero... but this can be observed at higher inductances.
- As a last resort, watch for heat and odor.

Comment: Sounds like an electromagnet to me with such labels. In this case emphasize flyback arcing. It can move magnetic objects (and itself) around it. When depends on the weight, magnetic moment and current level (not voltage per se)